# Multiple ssh connection with commands in each remote machine

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, scp, remote

I am trying to connect to 3 different remote machines, copy files between these machines and then stay in the final remote machine to perform a few tasks. I am trying to create a bash script to help me automate this process.  Here is what I will like to do

```
fname='file to be copied across these remote machines' 
rmt1='remote machine1'
mt2='remote machine2'
rmt3='remote machine3'

#copy file from local to rmt1
scp -r  $fname  $rmt1
#log into rmt1
ssh -Y $rmt1
#from rmt1, copy file from rmt1 to rmt2
scp -r  $fname  $rmt2
#from rmt1 log into rmt2
ssh -Y $rmt2
#from rmt2 copy file from rmt2 to rmt3
scp -r  $fname  $rmt3
#from rmt2 log into rmt3
ssh -Y $rmt3
Then finally stay in rmt3 where I can do other things.
```

I need a bash script to help me automate this process so that I don't have to type so much each time I need to do this. Any help will be highly appreciated. **Note** *I have enabled public/private  keys using **ssh-keygen** so any of these does not require me to enter a password*

Many thanks in anticipation for your help

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Always double-quote your variables when you use them. For example instead of `scp -r  $fname  $rmt3` use `scp -r  "$fname"  "$rmt3"`

Comment: Many thanks for this, I will take note of that henceforth.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the one private key on the local host will allow logins to all three remote hosts, and a modern version of OpenSSH, I would do it this way instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
fname='file to be copied across these remote machines' 
rmt1='remote machine1'
rmt2='remote machine2'
rmt3='remote machine3'

scp -J "$rmt1,$rmt2" "$fname" "$rmt3":/target/path/
ssh -Y -J "$rmt1,$rmt2" "$rmt3"
```

Comment: Double quotes around those variables

Comment: I already used `ssh-keygen` to remove asking for password all the time so it has no issues with password for now.

However, here is the error I  got.

Invalid -J argument
lost connection
Invalid -J argument

Comment: I did what you described and here is the error I got


```
Invalid -J argument
lost connection
Invalid -J argument
```

Comment: You might have an old version of OpenSSH that does not support the `-J` option. Please run `ssh -V` to identify the SSH version.

Comment: Here is the output `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`